# How to Fix Window Media Player Linking Warning in visual studio vb.net 2022

Tags: vb.net, wmplib

in window 10, I am using **window media player** in my vb.net 2022 application. I added Window Media Player Control in Toolbox and then added it in the form, I also set reference to it. but when I rebuild it, then it shows Warning like

***COM Reference 'WMPLib' is the interop assembly for ActiveX control 'AxWMPLib' but was marked to be linked by the compiler with the /link flag. This COM reference will be treated as a reference and will not be linked.**

How to fix this Warning.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. You don't have to do anything. If you want to clear the warning, do manually what it says it's going to do automatically. Not sure how to do that as it's not something I've ever done but there's an internet for you to search to find out.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney.  I have edited the question.